# Javascript: How to know which span did user add text to in contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If user put something before wordx in contenteditable div, e.g. somthingwordx, since the newly added text was not wrapped into any existed span, how do I know which span did user add text to?

Demo

```
<div id="inputbox" style="border:1px solid lightgrey" contenteditable="true">
  <span id="1">word1</span>  <span id="2">word2</span>
  <span id="3">word3</span>  <span id="4">word4</span>  <span id="5">word5</span>  <span id="6">word6</span>  <span id="7">word7</span>  <span id="8">word8</span>  <span id="9">word9</span>  <span id="10">word10</span>  <span id="11">word11</span>  <span id="12">word12</span>
</div>
```

Comment: add jsfiddle of what have you done so far..

Answer (score 0):

Use `DOMCharacterDataModified` event.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("inputbox");
div.addEventListener("DOMCharacterDataModified", function(e) {
  var elem = e.target.parentNode;
  console.log(elem);
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputbox" style="border:1px solid lightgrey" contenteditable="true">
  <span id="1">word1</span>  <span id="2">word2</span>
  <span id="3">word3</span>  <span id="4">word4</span>  <span id="5">word5</span>  <span id="6">word6</span>  <span id="7">word7</span>  <span id="8">word8</span>  <span id="9">word9</span>  <span id="10">word10</span>  <span id="11">word11</span>  <span id="12">word12</span>
</div>
```